# Get original URL after rewriting in Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel

Apache would choose a file to serve based on rewritten URL, but the original URL would be passed to the script.

Kestrel passes the rewritten URL down the pipeline (accessible via `HttpContext.Request.Path`).

**Is it possible to access original URL** from Middleware **after it has been rewritten?**

Comment: Write an middleware, read it pass it down the pipeline (via `HttpContext.Items` or any other means suitable for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the direction issued by @Tseng.  My test wraps the RewriteMiddleware, but you may want a separate middleware.

```
public class P7RewriteMiddleware
{
    private RewriteMiddleware _originalRewriteMiddleware;

    public P7RewriteMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        RewriteOptions options)
    {
        _originalRewriteMiddleware = new RewriteMiddleware(next, hostingEnvironment, loggerFactory, options);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the middleware.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="HttpContext"/> for the current request.</param>
    /// <returns>A task that represents the execution of this middleware.</returns>
    public new Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var currentUrl = context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString;
        context.Items.Add("original-path", currentUrl);
        return _originalRewriteMiddleware.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Later, my auth filter uses it.

```
if (spa.RequireAuth)
{
   context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult(Action, Controller,
         new { area = Area, returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Items["original-path"] });
}
```